# Chrome saved password list is empty

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Hi I am using Google Chrome on my mac Version Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)
and my mac running on 10.11.6 (15G1004) OSX EI Captain.

I can see chrome auto filling my passwords when I login to sites. But When I want to see my passwords, I am not able to see anything in the password list. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is Chrome filling them in or is it Keychain? Check by opening Keychain Access and looking for your passwords there.

Comment: I searched in Keychain...I could not find the url. I am not sure what is the right way to search keychain for chrome's saved passwords..

Comment: It's possible it's not in Keychain then, and is being saved by Chrome somewhere independently.